# Stanley 's example 1.1.11 and the exponential function

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, power-series, exponential-function

I opened Stanley's Enumerative combinatorics Vol. 1 and looked at example 1.1.11:

Suppose $F(0)=1$ and let $G(x)$ be the unique power series satisfying

$G'(x)=F'(x)/F(x)$,  $G(0)=0$.

The author wants to show the equivalence between this and the expression $F(x)=\exp G(x)$ of formal power series.

He lets $F(x)=1+\sum_{n \geq 1}a_nx^n$, computes the coefficients of $G(x)$ and $\exp G(x)$, and concludes that the latter must be polynomials in the $a_n$'s. He then states that the coefficients of $F(x)$ and $\exp G(x)$ must agree by invoking a uniqueness theorem of Taylor.

Could someone please elaborate on the authors intention or the point(s) he is trying to make, and perhaps give the proof with a bit of clarification or refer to an alternative. I was trying to let go of the analyst approach, but here the author seems to want to pass from the continuous setting to the extended one (judging by his "alternative method" that follows the one just given) by various forms of "function-theoretic" means, invoking various forms of convergence.

Comment: Where are you really stuck? Letting $F(x)=1+\sum_{n\ge1}a_nx^n$ seems like the most natural thing to do if the premise is that $F(0)=1$. Computing the coefficients of $\exp G(x)$ also suggests itself when your goals is to show that $F(x)=\exp G(x)$.

Comment: I am confused. What is given a priori in the problem statement, and what restricted class of functions $F$ does the author consider up until the point where he concludes that the identity $F(x)=\exp G(x)$ remain valid for formal power series? There is the convergence of $F$, and there is the neighbourhood in $\mathbb{C}^m$.

Comment: Please read the Wikipedia article [Formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) for precise definitions of of topology of convergence for formal power series, especially for $\exp(X).$